# Symfony setDataMapper

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

can someone explain me what the setDataMapper funtion in Symfony exactly does? I've build a buildForm function and trying to use the functions `mapDataToForms` and `mapFormsToData`. I'm working on Symfony 2.7

I don't know how to use the functions `mapDataToForms` and `mapFormsToData`

My code so far:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Types;

use AppBundle\Entity\Cities;
use AppBundle\Entity\ProfileCities;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataMapperInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;


class DataType extends AbstractType implements DataMapperInterface{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => ProfileCities::class
        ));
        $resolver->setDefault('label', false);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->setDataMapper($this);
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
            /** @var ProfileCities $cities */
            $cities = $event->getData();

            /** @var FormInterface $form */
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if (!is_null($cities)) {
                $form->add('isUsed', 'checkbox', array(
                    'label' => $cities->getCities()->getName()
                ));
            }
        });
    }

    public function mapDataToForms($data, $forms) {
        // TODO: Implement mapDataToForms() method.
    }

    public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$data) {
        // TODO: Implement mapFormsToData() method.
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'profile_cities';
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello welcome to Stack overflow please consider showing your effort and add code to the question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: see doc in progress https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/6900

Comment: https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/